# Conitnuous looping for while loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop

```
while (true) {
  if (memberName == subMemberGroup.indexOf("Leonardo", "Catherine", "Luther", "Bruce", "Amy") !== -1) {
    console.log("\nMember's name exists in database. Please enter a new name.");
    var memberName = input.question("Please enter member's name: ");
  } else break;
}
```

I am trying to loop through to see if "memberName" that the user has input matches any of the following strings in the "subMemberGroup" array.

However, when I tried using while loop, it keeps saying that Member's name exist even thought the "memberName" that the user input does not match the strings in "subMemberGroup" array. I tried using if statement with a break but it still does not work.

The reason why I used while loop is because I want my code to re-prompt the user the enter a new name if the "memberName" matches the strings in "subMemberGroup" array.

Comment: What is `input.question()`?

Comment: input.question is basically just prompting the user a question

Comment: `if (memberName == subMemberGroup.indexOf("Leonardo", "Catherine", "Luther", "Bruce", "Amy") !== -1)` makes no sense.

Comment: the reason why I did that was so that I am able to check if the user input matches any of the strings in the array

Comment: `memberName == something` returns `true` or `false`. Why are you comparing that with `-1`?

Comment: If you want to know if a string is in an array, use `array.includes(string)`

Comment: `indexOf()` only takes one argument, why are you calling it with 5 names? What is `subMemberGroup`?

Comment: `while (true) { memberName = input.question(...); if (subMemberGroup.includes(memberName)){ display error; } else { break }}`

Comment: subMemberGroup contains the arrays ["Leonardo", "Catherine", "Luther", "Bruce", "Amy"].

So i am comparing if the user's input matches any of the string in the array

Comment: Why do you think you need to put the contents of the array in the arguments? They're already in the array. The argument should be what you're testing.

Comment: memberName contains the user's input.

from there, I would like to compare if memberName matches any of the strings in subMemberGroup array. That was my logic behind my code above. Sorry if it was confusing.

Comment: The error im getting is that even though memberName does not equals to any of the strings in subMemberGroup array, it still prompts that the name has existed which makes no sense.

Comment: I can't reproduce: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/qkvg6dx8/1/

Comment: Well I just want to know why the while loop doesn't break when the if condition is false.

Comment: from my code above, it doesnt make sense if I put john and it still goes through the loop even though its false

Comment: Did you use my condition? Your condition is simply wrong.

Comment: I tried using your condition but im not sure why is it wrong still. while (true) {
            if (subMemberGroup.includes(memberName)) {
            console.log ("\nMember's name exists in database. Please enter a new name.");
            var memberName = input.question("Please enter member's name: ");
            }
            else break;
        }

Comment: You're asking for input *after* the `if` check. You need to get it first. See my jsfiddle.

Comment: is there another way of doing it?

Comment: I tried your coding, but it doesnt give me the right output

Comment: Did you try my fiddle? If you enter `Luther` it repeats. If you enter `Joe` it stops. What else do you expect?

Comment: Yes, I tried your fiddle. But when I applied it to my viual studio code, it doesnt give me the same result compared to when im using the fiddle.

Comment: Is there a way that would make it work in visual studio code?